# Android Multitasking when ProgressDialog shows in screen

Tags: android

In Android, I have a screen with setting menu, when loading the screen I am displaying message using `ProgressDialog` "Please  wait.while screen loads" until the search is completed.

I want to access the setting menu in the screen when search is currently on and the `ProgressDialog` is still displaying on the screen.

I tried `progressDialog.cancel()`, but this hides the progress dialog message and then allow me to the menu.  But I want to show the dialog message while accessing the menu. Is it possible to display the Progress dialog message when the user access the settings menu.

Comment: It's kind of contradictory to say "Please wait" while allowing the user to access what it is waiting for. You might need to be more clear on what you are trying to achieve. About the closest thing I can think of that you want to do is to use a notification instead of a progress dialog

Comment: i want to display progress dialog message to user until the search completed. When the 
 search operation is still going on , i should be able to access menu the in same screen also should display the progress dialog , because search is not  over yet.

Comment: Not using a ProgressDialog this way. You could add a View (like a TextView) and toggle visibility while it's searching. Still sounds confusing to me thought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your requirements, you probably shouldn't be using a `ProgressDialog`, as it will "lock" the user actions until you cancel it (or the user dismiss it by pressing the back button).

Another solution would be to create a view with a centered `ProgressBar` and a `TextView`, and set its initial visibility to `GONE`, then once you start loading your search, you can change this view visibility to `VISIBLE` and everything else to `GONE` (except for the things you want to be visible, like your menu).

With that said, you'll get something like the screenshot below:

[image: Sample loading screen]

That way, the user will be able to interact with other components on the screen such as accessing the settings menu.

The XML code is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="LOADING..."
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/progressBar"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I have used ProgressBar and TextView, it is working , thank you for the answer Mauker.